# Multiple producers for a single resolver/promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

In the Q documentation there is this line:

"You can give the resolver to any number of producers and whoever resolves the promise first wins. Furthermore, none of the producers can observe that they lost unless you give them the promise part too."

I don't really get what that is saying.  Is this for when you are constructing a promise by hand?  Can someone give me an example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this for when you are constructing a promise by hand?

Exactly, you can create a promise with a deferred or the promise constructor, call `resolve` multiple times but only the first time is effectful. For example:

```
var p = new Q.Promise(function(resolve){
    resolve(1);
    resolve(2);
    resolve(3);
    resolve(4);
    resolve(5); // can also pass `resolve` around.
});

p.then(function(result){
    // always 1, all other calls had no effect.
});
```

This lets you build interesting things, for example let's build a `race` function that returns the result of the first to resolve of two promises (error handling omitted for brevity):

```
function race(p1, p2){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        p1.then(resolve);
        p2.then(resolve);
    });
}
```

Which would resolve with whichever promise is ready first, for example:

```
race(tryToGetFromFirstAPI(), tryToGetFromSecondAPI()).then(function(result){
   // resolves as soon as the "fastest" resolved, with the result
});
```

Comment: Is this behavior A+? Does bluebird and native do the same under these scenarios?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha A+ only specifies _interoperability_ between promise libraries, it does not specify the promise constructor. The promise constructor specification and the ECMAScript specification specify that. Yes, all of them behave the same.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I recently raised an eyebrow at that statement. Unfortunately you need already to understand Deferreds/Promises in order to understand what is actually meant.

For me, the problem starts with the introductory sentence :

> Deferreds are cool because they separate the promise part from the resolver part. So:

This is misleading because Deferreds don't actually *separate* these components - it's more accurate to say that they *combine* them, but allow their separation if required.

Off the cuff, better wording would be :

> Deferreds [are cool because they] include the means to derive a Promise and include, in the form of executable methods, the means to resolve or reject, all wrapped up in a single object. So:"

The sentence starting "You can give the promise to any number of consumers ..." is a bit wordy but otherwise fine.

But the sentence starting "You can give the resolver to any number of producers ..." would better read :

> The resolve and/or reject methods are readily detachable allowing you, for example, to pass them to any number of producers and whoever resolves/rejects first wins; furthermore, by passing the detached methods and not the Deferred itself (and hence its Promise), none of the producers can observe whether they won or lost."

A third statement might also be included :

> A Deferred can be passed in its entirety, complete with its means to resolve/reject and to derive a Promise."

In fact, all of the above *can*, with a little jiggery-pokery, also be achieved with the `new Promise(synchronousSettlerFunction)` construction and outer var(s).

It should also be said that statements like this can be reviewed and improved many times over. My attempts above took me 15 minutes so I wouldn't pretend they are the last word.

Comment: So make a pull request :)?

Comment: I could make a life-long career from Q documentation pull requests :-)

Comment: So what is a producer?

Comment: "Producer" is a term used in that section of the Q doc and I'm not aware of similar usage anywhere else. From the context we understand it to mean "function that causes a Deferred to resolve or reject - ie to settle - but not necessarily the function that created the Deferred".